# Codeigniter Hooks - post_controller_constructor is not working

Tags: php, codeigniter, hook

I am trying to work some procedures after controller constructor is called. I have tried using the sample code below but the codeigniter hook is not working. I used lambda/anoymous functions as hooks.

config.php

```
$config['enable_hooks'] = TRUE;
```

hooks.php

```
$hook['post_controller_constructor'] = function() {
    echo "post controller constructor was called";
};
```

Answer (score 1):

The most likely reason is that somewhere along the way a call to `exit` or `die()` was made. That or some unreported error/exception is happening.

Your example works perfectly on my v3.1.9 test setup.